# Simulator error: "Unable to boot the simulator" macOS EI Caption version :10.11.4 (15E65)

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

I have reset content and settings of simulator, create simulator after deleting it and reinstall Xcode7.3 but still same error message appears:

[image]

Comment: i am also getting the same issue. does anybody know why this error is occuring?

Comment: reset the  simulator.

Comment: Quit the xcode and run it again + Clean your app

Comment: I have try it but not working

Comment: Tried everything @iDeveloper

Comment: I have solve it by reinstall mac OS and then install Xcode

Comment: and i have solved by update mac os from ei captain  to Sierra. :)

Comment: A more detailed message (including the reason for the failure) can be found in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log ... what does it reveal as the reason for the failure?